# background-image with a text

Tags: html, css

My goal is to get a result like this:
[image]

For now, I would like the text to be in the background image.
I think my problem is perhaps in my blocks HTML ?

Here is an overview 
[image]

```css
.background_grey {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.page_title {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<img class="background_grey" src="images/subtle_grunge.png" />
<div class="page_title">Register <span class="hometxtcolor">an Account</span></div>
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a background image via CSS, not from an img element:

```css
.page_title {
  background-image: url(images/subtle_grunge.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="page_title">
  Register
  <span class="hometxtcolor">
          an Account
        </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

Find Complete solution here...